# ORBER BY clause makes query slow despite small result set

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, query-optimization

I have the following tables (irrelevant things removed):

```
create table Payment (
    id int not null auto_increment,
    status int not null,
    primary key(id)
);
create table Booking (
    id int not null auto_increment,
    paymentId int not null,
    nrOfPassengers int not null,
    primary key(id),
    key paymentFK (paymentId),
    constraint paymentFK foreign key (paymentId) references Payment(id)
);
```

`Booking` contains ~456k rows and `Payment` contains ~331k rows. The following query takes 0.06s and returns 97 rows:

```
select * from Booking b
join Payment p on b.paymentId = p.id
where p.status = 3
```

If I add an `order by` clause, the query instead takes 4.4s, almost 100 times slower:

```
select * from Booking b
join Payment p on b.paymentId = p.id
where p.status = 3
order by b.nrOfPassengers
```

EXPLAIN for the first query:

```
id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key,       key_len, ref,  rows,   Extra
1,  SIMPLE,      p,     ALL,  PRIMARY,       NULL,      NULL,    NULL, 331299, Using where
1,  SIMPLE,      b,     ref,  paymentFK,     paymentFK, 9,       p.id, 1,      Using where
```

and for the second:

```
id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key,       key_len, ref,  rows,   Extra
1,  SIMPLE,      p,     ALL,  PRIMARY,       NULL,      NULL,    NULL, 331299, Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1,  SIMPLE,      b,     ref,  paymentFK,     paymentFK, 9,       p.id, 1,      Using where
```

I use MySQL 5.1.34.

The `where` clause used in the query filters out the vast majority of rows from `Payment`. I get the impression that MySQL sorts the result set before filtering it with the (highly selective) `where` clause. Am I right in this? If so, why does it do this? I've tried analyzing both tables, but with no change in the query plans.

Comment: do you have an index defined?

Comment: I'm a little surprised that `paymentid` is not a component of `booking`'s PRIMARY KEY.

Comment: Definitely puzzling. Could it be possibly you are reaching a RAM limit causing virtual memory to kick in?

Comment: define an index on column status, then try again

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you have the appropriate indexes on your tables.  Assuming you do and it's still slower than expected, you could throw your results in a subquery without ordering them, and then add the ORDER BY clause back:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
   select * from Booking b
   join Payment p on b.paymentId = p.id
   where p.status = 3
)
ORDER BY nrOfPassengers
```

I'm not sure how much (or if) this will help as when I view the execution plan it adds a row, but it like it could be quicker.

Good luck.

Comment: How do you think your query might help? Your train of thought is actually very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

I have a suspicion, that the problem is that among irrelevant things you removed there is a `TEXT` or `BLOB` column which makes MySQL go ondisk to store the intermediate result from the temporary table.

In any case, what we see from the execution plan:
For each row from the `Payment` table, fetch it from disk, check condition, if it is true for each matching row in `Booking` put result in a temporary table. Sort the whole table with all the data by `nrOfPassengers` and output. In case, there are `Text` or `Blob` fields, the intermediate table is stored and sorted on disk, since MySQL can not predict the size of the table.

What you can do (as usual) is to minimize disk operations. As @ajreal suggested, add an index on `status` column. If it is so selective, you won't need any other indexes, but if you extend your `paymentFK` to `(paymentId, nrOfPassengers)` it will be even better. Now rewrite the query as follows:

```
SELECT p.*, b.*
FROM (
  select p.id as paymentId, b.id as bookingId
  from Booking b
  join Payment p on b.paymentId = p.id
  where p.status = 3
  order by b.nrOfPassengers
) as ids
JOIN Payment p ON ids.paymentId = p.id
JOIN Booking b ON ids.bookingId = b.id;
```

The data will be output in the subquery order.

Comment: The table does not contain any `TEXT` or `BLOB` columns. Only `VARCHAR`, `INT`, `BIGINT`, `DECIMAL`, `BIT` and `DATETIME`. However, adding an index on `status` made both the original query and your query instant. I still can't say I understand why the `order by` had such an impact on the performance of the original query.

Comment: @ViktorDahl, the first query does not require a temporary table to store data before sorting, and can not predict the size of the table in the second query, because there is no statistics how many rows with `p.status=3` there are.